# How can I clear scrollback and reset with a keyboard shortcut, rather than the mouse, in xfce4-terminal?

Tags: xfce

xfce4-terminal does not advertise a keyboard shortcut for "Clear Scrollback and Reset," although you can pick it from the Terminal menu. Is there a way? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *Clear Scrollback and Reset* in xfce4-terminal without using the mouse, use the keyboard combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Note that this can only be done when the xfce4-terminal menu is visible. To toggle the menu, press <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: And only with EN locale, when menu item title 'Terminal'

Comment: Since my menu is always hidden, it's convenient to press F10 then T then C.

Answer (score 4):

You can custom configure hot keys via config file:

```
nano ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm
```

Find and replace for set up hot key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> Clear Scrollback and Reset:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/reset-and-clear" "<Primary><Shift>l")
```